# Не читаются русские символы (строки) из файла (C)

Tags: c, gcc, utf-8

Программа должна прочесть построчно строки русских символов из файла в массив и вывести их на экран. Компилятор gcc, Linux. Текстовый файл в кодировке utf8. Строки из английских символов читаются, строки русских символов нет. Программа уходит в бесконечный цикл т.к. символ конца файла никогда не возвращается.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");

FILE *fp;
wchar_t arrayofwords[64][64];
int i;
i=0;

    if (argc!=2) {
        printf("Не указан исходный файл!\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    if ((fp = fopen (argv[1],"r")) == NULL){
        printf("Ошибка при открытии файла!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (!feof(fp)){
        if (fgetws(arrayofword[i], 63, fp) != NULL){
            wprintf(L"%s\n", arrayofwords[i]);
        i++;
        }
    }
fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: в твоей программе File *fp; не задан, думаю ты знаешь об етом.    {#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;
   int c;
  
   fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
   while(1)
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) )
      { 
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   
   return(0);
}      }

Comment: в смысле не указан файл?

Answer (score 3):

Программа зацикливается, т.к. функция `fgetws()` возвращает NULL как при конце файла, так и в случае какой-либо ошибки (в данном случае -- `errno = 84: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`). Указатель чтения в файле при этом остается на месте, т.е. конца файла Вы никогда не достигаете.

*Для проверки можете добавить*:

```
  else if (ferror(fp)) 
      err(2, "fgetws errno = %d", errno);
```

*после*

```
if (fgetws(arrayofword[i], 63, fp) != NULL){
  ...
}
```

Данная ошибка возникает, поскольку локаль `"Russian"` системе неизвестна. В Вашем случае `setlocale()` возвращает NULL, и этой ошибке соответствует -- `errno = 2 setlocale: No such file or directory`.

В общем, чтобы программа заработала, достаточно установить подходящую локаль:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_SG.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

вызвать `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` и подправить в Вашем выводе формат  на `L"%ls\n"` (как пояснено в ответе @Roman Khimov),
*а также анализировать результат вызова функций и правильно реагировать на ошибки*.

P.S.
Поскольку локали далеко не всегда установлены, да и функции для работы с `wchar_t` иногда крайне болезненно  реагируют на ошибки во входных данных (та самая `Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`), да и более того,  например, вывод функций `printf`/`wprintf` не получается смешивать,
я предпочитаю 
 **работать с UTF напрямую** (поскольку это просто последовательность байт (`char *`), то в большинстве случаев стандартных `printf`, `scanf`, `strcmp` и т.п. вполне хватает), т.е. **не переводя в wchar_t**. Если же требуется перевод в `wchar_t` (UCS) (и обратно, а также некоторые специфические функции), то использую свои функции (из [ucsutf.h](http://pastebin.com/gg6Xe9KL), [ucsutf.c](http://pastebin.com/iCC2k7RW)), которые **не зависят от setlocale()**.

Answer (score 1):

Если не считать того, что:

- `arrayofwords` может быть элементарно переполнен большим файлом
- строки длиннее 64 (вместе с переводом строки) символов будут восприняты как несколько строк
- `setlocale()` лучше бы делать в виде `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")`, пользователю (и его окружению) такое должно бы быть виднее
- прочитанный (и помещённый в буфер) перевод строки из файла при выводе будет дополнен ещё одним (может быть, конечно, так и надо, но)
- `fgetws()` можно отдать 64, а не 63, так как прочитано будет на один символ меньше и нулевой символ будет добавлен в любом случае
- проверку `feof()` можно убрать, вполне достаточно проверки результата `fgetws()`

То мне сложно сказать, почему такая программа будет зацикливаться при конечном входном файле. Однако, неплохо видно, почему она выводит мусор вместо ожидаемых данных (надо отметить, не читает, а именно выводит, читает она всё исправно), вместо

```
wprintf(L"%s\n", arrayofwords[i]);
```

имеет смысл написать

```
wprintf(L"%ls\n", arrayofwords[i]);
```

Поскольку в отсутствие модификатора `l` передаваемый параметр воспринимается как `const char *` и подвергается преобразованию через `mbrtowc()` перед выводом (прямо [как в мануале написано](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=wprintf&category=3&russian=0)). В нашем же случае это уже не нужно, а при наличии `l` параметр воспринимается уже как `const wchar_t *` и выводится как есть.